# Installing paramik / Crypto on ubuntu

Tags: python

I have downloaded and installed paramik from github, [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko); but can't manage it to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/home/superiois/Downloads/paramiko-master/paramiko/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/home/superiois/Downloads/paramiko-master/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko import util
  File "/home/superiois/Downloads/paramiko-master/paramiko/util.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "/home/superiois/Downloads/paramiko-master/paramiko/common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

I believe my Crypto is up to date; by simply I cant make this command into work "from Crypto import Random". I appreciate any hint

Comment: Can you launch an interpreter and type in `import Crypto`? Then, if that works, `print Crypto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I tried it (OS X):

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/paramiko/paramiko.git
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>>
```

I do notice that it requires [PyCrypto != 2.4](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/setup.py#L43); is it possible that's the version you have installed?  How did you install paramiko/PyCrypto?